# show that $B^{T}AB$ is positive-definite if and only if $B$ is invertible.

Tags: numerical-methods

Given that $A \in R^{n,n}$ is symmetric and positive-definite and $B \in R^{n,n}$,show that $B^{T}AB$ is positive-definite if and only if $B$ is invertible.
That's what I have done so far:
We suppose that $C=B^{T}AB$ is positive-definite,that means that $\forall x\in R^{n}-\{0\}$ : $0<x^{T}Cx=x^{T}B^{T}ABx=y^{T}Ay , \text{ where } y=Bx$.
But how can I conclude that $B$ is invertible?

Comment: Since $B$ is positive then all eigen values are positive, so its determinant is positive as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have for $X\in\mathbb R^{n,1}$ and since $A$ is definite positive
$$X^TB^TABX=(BX)^TA(BX)\ge0$$
hence $B^TAB$ is positive,
moreover
$$X^TB^TABX=(BX)^TA(BX)=0\iff BX=0$$
so

- if $B$ is invertible then $X=0$ so $B^TAB$ is definite
- and if $B^TAB$ is definite so $BX=0\iff X=0$ and then $B$ is invertible.

Comment: If a matrix $A$ is positive-definite,doesn't it mean that: $x^{T}Ax>0$ ? Or can it also be equal to $0$ ?

Comment: It's equal $0$ only for $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $C$ positive definite gives us that $Bx \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$. Hence kernel $B={0}$.

So B is invertible.

I think you have got the converse (since you didn't ask about it). Essentially the converse follows similar line of argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B^TAB$ is positive definite, it is invertible, since the inequality $x^TB^TABx > 0$, which our OP has astutely derived and graciously provided,  implies $\ker B^TAB = 0$.  $B^TAB$ invertible implies $\det (B^TAB) \ne 0$.  But $\det (B^TAB) = \det(B^T) \det (A) \det(B)$, so $\det(B) \ne 0$; hence $B$ itself must be invertible.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***